# 'for' loop and modulo

Tags: javascript, loops, modulo

I've just started to learn JS and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the basics behind the 'for' loop.

Example:

```
for (var number = 3; number % 7 == 0; number++)
```

Why doesn't it make sense? Why do I have to write it down like that:

```
for (var number = 3; ; number++) {
  if (number % 7 == 0)
    break; 
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: The middle part of the loop tells you the condition that makes it keep running, not the condition that makes it stop. Therefore, to achieve the piece of code on the bottom, you should have used `number % 7 != 0` instead of `==`

Comment: Thank you! That was the point!

Comment: You should accept @melpomene's answer.

Comment: I'm going to, but I've some error atm while pressing the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've inverted the condition. The middle part of a `for` loop tells you what must be true for the loop to continue. Your second version uses the same condition to decide when to stop.

---

```
for (A; B; C) { ... }
```

can be (mostly) rewritten as

```
A;
while (B) {
    ...
    C;
}
```

(The difference is that `continue` in a `for` loop will still execute the `C` part.)

Initially your `number` is 3. Then we do the equivalent of `while (number % 7 == 0) { ... }`, but that condition fails (`3 % 7` is 3, not 0), so the loop never runs.

---

You probably wanted

```
for (var number = 3; number % 7 != 0; number++)
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! Now I understand that :) Thanks!!